# Return value of operator++

Tags: c++

I have the following code that is broken. I can fix it by modifying certain line in code (see the comment). What is the cause of the problem?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Number{
public:
    int n;
    Number(int a):n(a){}

    //when I change the following to
    //friend Number& operator++(Number& source, int i)
    //then it compiles fine and correct value is printed
    friend Number operator++(Number& source, int i){
        ++source.n;
        return source;
    }
};

int main() {

    Number x(5);
    x++++; //error: no 'operator++(int)' declared for postfix '++' [-fpermissive]
    cout<<x.n;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why does this surprise you? Think of the semantics of postfix `operator++`, what you are returning, what you are trying to do and to whom you're trying to do it to.

Comment: why do you need `friend` in your code?

Comment: @triclosan it is not necessary here, but assuming he has a private member and wants a global function as opposed to member overload?

Comment: @triclosan Because operator++ is unary and if it was a member function, it would have just one argument (the int). I believe this version with two arguments is not a member function (even though it is defined inside the class) and therefore the friend is needed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You attempt to apply the second `++` to the temporary object returned by the first invocation. However, the operand must be passed by reference, and you can't bind a temporary to a non-constant *lvalue* reference.

You probably don't want to "fix" this, since there's little reason to modify a temporary value like that. However, you should return a copy of the value *before* incrementing it, to give the expected post-increment behaviour.

The prefix operator should return a reference, which can be happily bound to another reference so that `++++x;` should work as expected.

Comment: The problem is that the postfix increment *can't* return by reference because it will return the already-incremented value!

Comment: @MarkB: So it can't; I wasn't reading the code properly.

Comment: Why is he making `operator++` a `friend` to begin with?

Comment: @NikBougalis: Because, when you're not writing a toy class as a demonstration, you'd probably want the data members to be private. Although it could be a member, if you prefer.

Comment: @MikeSeymour why would you want a `++` operator as a non-member friend? I see no reason.

Comment: @NikBougalis: One good reason to make it a non-member is so you'll get an error rather than unexpected results if you write `x++++;`, as demonstrated by the question.

Answer (score 8):

You are incrementing the return value of the inner `operator++` by writing `x++ ++`. That means that the code won't compile if the return value of that operator is not something that can be modified.

So if you declare it to return `Number` instead of `Number &`, then it can't be modified (the return value of a function is a temporary and not an lvalue unless it's a reference, hence the outer operator++, which takes it by (non-const) reference, can't bind it to an object returned by value).

Comment: You can modify temporaries/rvalues of class types just fine. The problem is that you can't chain the operators if you return by value because the operator takes the first argument by non-const reference.

Comment: @jrok (I actually suspected something like that but I wasn't sure.) So, would this be correct if I added "hence the outer `operator++`, which takes it by (non-const) reference, can't bind it to an object returned by value"?

Comment: That'd be fine, me thinks.

Comment: Now, prepare for some horror: **[ref-qualified member functions work in clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=f47668cc0c7e3c7614903f1f2421d131-16ccd8065d089fe1982fc39c3a92e82f)!** (of course there is no use case, but still :/) PS: Did you get my [invite](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34803/lets-talk)?

Comment: @sehe Oh, holy... No, I didn't get it yet, heading over to the link :)

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to do is very unusual. Post-increment usually returns an rvalue representing the object **before** the increment (as opposed to pre-increment, which first increments the object and then returns that object itself, as an lvalue). You are basically trying to make post-increment behave the same way as pre-increment, for inexplicable reasons.

Normally, you would do something like this:

```
class Number {
  int n;
public:
  // Pre-increment
  Number& operator++() {
    ++n;
    return *this;
  }
  Number operator++(int) {
    Number temp = *this;  // capture old value
    ++(*this);
    return temp;
  }
};
```

With this definition, `x++++` doesn't compile - but it also doesn't compile when `x` is an `int`: it doesn't really make much sense.

Anyway, the reason it doesn't work for you is as follows. `x++++` is interpreted as

```
operator++(operator++(x, 0), 0)
```

The inner `operator++` call returns a temporary `Number` object. The outer `operator++()` expects a parameter of type `Number&` - but a non-const reference can't bind to a temporary. When you change the declaration so that `operator++` returns `Number&` - an lvalue - then this return value can be happily passed to the outer `operator++` call.

Comment: I think given your code, `x++++` actually will compile, since `x.operator++(0).operator++(0)` is well-formed.  You could fix this by declaring member `Number operator++(int) &` (but only rather recent gcc/clang versions support that, and AFAIK no Microsoft compilers do).

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik aschepler is right - it does compile. Anyway I get the point, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start out by observing that you can't chain postincrement operators like this for `int` either!

Then before I get t o the problem let me suggest to just not write unintuitive code like this. Someone will have to read your program a year from now and you want to make that as easy to grok as possible.

Consider that `x++++` is really something like `operator++(operator++(x, int), int)` So now what's happening is that the first `operator++` returns by value (which results in an unnamed temporary being returned). This unnamed temporary cannot be bound to the non-const reference parameter to the second (outer) call and the method lookup fails.

Finally note that your implementation doesn't actually implement postfix increment: It implements prefix increment. You should either remove the `int` parameter (which signals postfix) or fix the implementation to return the unmodified value.